# play framework:what Is the difference between play.api.mvc and play.mvc packages

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

while I working with play I encounter two choices 
`play.api.mvc` and `play.mvc` packages

what Is the difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the play! 2 documentation:

> The API available in the play.api package (such as play.api.mvc)
>   is reserved for Scala developers. As a Java developer, look at play.mvc.

Source: [Play for Java developers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaHome)

Comment: Thanks! Why not use "scala*" and "java*" names, as Akka actually did?  That is the question!